# Draw Rentangle inside a MovieClip ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have a map consisting of MovieClip cities inside it and I have a click function in top layer of map MovieClip. I try to do that if I click a city, a rectangle will be drawn. Here is code:

```
function rpress(a)
{
trace( "trying" );

    var b:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    b.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    b.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,80);
    b.graphics.endFill();
    b.x = 150;
    b.y = 150;
    addChild( b );
trace("done")
}
```

Trace commands are executed but no rectangle is drawn. I tried `MovieClip( root ).addChild..., stage.addChild..., MovieClip( parent ).addChild...` and others...

Do you have any idea? Thank you!

FULL CODE:

Double Click map MovieClip->84 layers welcome us->Chose the layer named "Action Layer" ACTIONS-FRAME:

```
function rbtxt(a)
{
    var _loc2 = a;
    var _loc3 = this;
    balon._visible = true;
    arbtxt = ilad.split(",");
    balon.txt.text = arbtxt[_loc2];
    _loc3["x" + _loc2].play();
    balon._x = _loc3["x" + _loc2]._x;
    balon._y = _loc3["x" + _loc2]._y - _loc3["x" + _loc2]._height / 2 + 5;
}
//End of the function
function rbalon(a)
{
    balon._visible = false;
    this["x" + a].gotoAndStop(1);
}
//End of the function
function rpress(a)
{
trace( "trying" );

    var b:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    b.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    b.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,80);
    b.graphics.endFill();
    b.x = 150;
    b.y = 150;
    addChild(b );
trace("done")
}

ilad = "CITY NAMES....."
ilurl = "CITY URLS....."
```

Comment: Sprite but how? Like var b:Sprite = new Sprite(); ? If you meaned that it doesn't work... It gives " 'Sprite' could not be loaded " error.

Comment: Can you post your .fla or full code?  You're rpress() function looks fine, so it must be something else.

Comment: Okey, I will edit my post now.

Comment: Still don't have much context,  how is rpress() called?   You said you tried stage.addChild(b) and still didn't see the rectangle?     How do you get rid of the rectangle later?

Comment: rpress() is called when you click a city MovieClip as

on (release)
{
    _parent.rpress(a);
}

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing enough code, so we can only guess. By looking at the info you supplied you could try:

```
this["x" + a].addChild( b );
```

or

```
balon.addChild( b );
```

But this is only guessing...

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to add the movie clip to the stage and then execute the drawing camamnd like this

```
 var b:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    addChild(b );
    b.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    b.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,80);
    b.graphics.endFill();
    b.x = 150;
    b.y = 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sprite has access to graphics, try and only use Movieclip for complex objects such as SWFs loaded in and Flash library assets with timeline based animation and variables etc

```
function drawRect()
{
    trace( "trying" );

    //var b:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var b:Sprite = new Sprite();
    b.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    b.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,80);
    b.graphics.endFill();
    b.x = 150;
    b.y = 150;
    addChild( b );
    trace("done")
}
```

Comment: To be even more minimalistic and lightweight we could use the Shape class. Btw. I don't know why you got down voted, because it is a good point, anyway it wasn't me, I would need 150 reputation to be able to be that cruel ;)

Comment: Shape class would be most efficient... this isn't an answer to the question though and would be more appropriate in the comments.

Comment: Im not here to do other peoples jobs for them but point them in the right direction. I will just post links to adobe live docs from now on. People geez.